# Complement of a given Language for a DFA

Tags: state-machine, finite-automata, dfa

For DFA, the alphabet Σ = {a,b} the language this DFA will recognise is `{w|w must contain a}`. For this language that the DFA recognises, what would be the compliment of this language or how would it be written please?
I can't work out if `b` should also be in the compliment of the language or not. `a` I know should be excluded from the compliment as it is in the original L or language.

I would have posted an image of the alphabet but I don't have enough points or reputation to.

I am unable to determine the complement of the language that the DFA recognises

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/dfa_complement.htm

Comment: Does the word `b` contain `a`? If it does, then it's part of the original language and not part of the complement. If it does not, then it's not part of the original language and part of the complement. A word will be in *exactly one* of a language and its complement.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of the language {w in {a, b}* | w must contain a} is the language {w in {a, b}* | w contains no a}. Strings in this language can be empty or consist of any number of b; the regular expression for this is b* and there is a 2-state minimal DFA that loops on the accepting initial state in case of b, and goes to a non-accepting dead state in case of a, where both transitions from the dead state are loops back to the dead state itself.